# Get Lyrics iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I was wondering if there was a class available that can retrieve lyrics for a song title? Is there any iPhone compatible API available?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://lyrics.wikia.com/LyricWiki:REST

Says it has a XML response as well. You can very well parse XML efficiently with the NSXML parser